# Best way to stay informed on an author without much of a web presence?

Tags: authors, ted-chiang

I am a Ted Chiang fan and I find it quite frustrating that he has no website, no Twitter account, no Facebook account etc.

What is the best way to stay in touch with the man and his work short of setting up a Google alert?

Comment: I think this is somewhat offtopic, but not sure. Anyway, Google alert is probably the best, especially coupled with alert on his Wikipedia page. Or may be check if his publisher has a web page for him presuming he keeps to the same publisher consistently.

Comment: As an alternative, **contact the author, and offer to serve as his webmaster/social media flack** - that way you get to know the news before everyone, you get to help your favorite author, and heck, you get to help fellow fans and probably market his work - for which he just might decide to pay you :)  He sounds like a type of person who just might appreciate the offer (a geek who wouldn't necessarily want to bother with pubclicity efforts on his own)

Comment: The advice in this question can be applied to any author without a big web presence.

Comment: @AgnelKurian - Have edited the question title so it can be helpful to more people - just about any advice given here can be applied to any other author without a website or twitter account, etc. Please roll back my edits if I've missed the mark.

Comment: Find his address, move in next door. Set up a cam feed.

Comment: @so12311 - If he didn't want you to read his emails, he'd have chosen a more secure password.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of ways to do this would be to keep an eye on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Chiang), find [fan sites that focus on his work](http://daganbooks.com/), or just [keep an eye on Amazon for him](https://www.amazon.com/Ted-Chiang/e/B001HCZ6OA/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1). And if you are really frustrated, create a blog devoted to him, where you religiously look at everything you can so as to help others like yourself.

Comment: There's the blog [Ted Chiang(ology)](http://tedchiang.blogspot.com/), but it looks like a spam/scraper blog. There's certainly room for a better blog!

Comment: The second link behaves funny. Would you maybe have a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Speculative Fiction Database page on [Chiang](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Ted_Chiang) is probably your best bet.